# Square root and similarity between integer matrices

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-analysis, matrix-congruences

> Prove or disprove:
>
> Let $A, B \in \operatorname{M}(3,\mathbb{Z})$ and $A \sim B$.
> $A$ has a square root in $\operatorname{M}(3,\mathbb{Z})$ iff $B$ has a square root in $\operatorname{M}(3,\mathbb{Z})$.

If $AX = XB$ for some invertible $X$ in $\operatorname{M}(3,\mathbb{Z})$ with $\det(X) = 1$, then it is true. What if $\det(X)$ is not equal to $1$ or $-1$ ?

Comment: Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then, $A$ and $B$ are similar over the rationals. Now, $B$ has a square root over the integers (namely, $A$). Something makes me think that $A$ has none, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: Ah, I see: $A$ has no square root over the integers, since $A$ has no square roots over $\mathbb{F}_2$. This does not completely answer the question, seeing that my $A$ and $B$ are $2 \times 2$ rather than $3 \times 3$, but it makes a positive answer very unlikely.

Comment: @darijgrinberg - your example extends to $3\times 3$ by simply adding another row and column with $0$s everywhere except on the diagonal where it is $1$. And the similarity matrix $X$ can be integer, though the determinant will not be $1$, so the inverse matrix will not be integer. For example, $X =\text{diag}(1,2,1)$ works.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Yeah, but I'm not sure whether the extended matrix still won't have a square root over the integers. At least my modulo-$2$ argument doesn't carry over.

Comment: I already proved it. Tnk u so much anyway